# Why Kotlin is not allowing me to add elements to a Array list

Tags: arraylist, kotlin

I have a Kotlin object which I am constructing from a API response

`schedule:  Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`

my object looks like below.

> {0=[0, 2.00, 23.59], 1=[1, 2.00, 23.59], 2=[2, 2.00, 23.59], 4=[4,
>   2.00, 23.59], 5=[5, 2.00, 23.59], 6=[6, 2.00, 23.59]}

At some point, I would like to add/delete an entry from the collection. For example, after my 3rd object, I would like to add an entry

> 3=[3, 2.00, 23.59].

What I tried so far is `schedule.schedule.plus()` method unsuccessfully.

This should allow me to add a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>` But it wouldn't?

Update: Following has helped me add the desired object but Now I cannot seem to sort the collection.

```
var list =  ArrayList<String>()
list.add(0,"2")
list.add(1,"23")
schedule.schedule?.put(num.toString(),list)
```

Comment: `Map` is immutable. Use `MutableMap` instead.

Comment: you sure you tried `schedule.schedule.plus()`?

Comment: Yes I am sure I tried plus()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following two has helped me add or remove entries.

Add

```
 var list =  ArrayList<String>()
 list.add(0,num.toString())
 list.add(1,"5.0")
 list.add(2,"14.0")
 schedule.schedule?.put(num.toString(),list)
```

And for removal.

```
schedule.schedule.remove("0")
```

But I had to change the `Map` to `MutableMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a value to a list then use `plusAssign()` function. because the `plus()` method is just like the behaviour as  a = b + c and the `plusAssign()` is a+=b.

Comment: To use the full power of kotlin use += sign.